# Fixed position footer that moves as page scrolls

Tags: jquery, scroll, footer, offset, sticky

I have a single page wordpress website with menu items that scroll down the page. Currently my footer is at the bottom of the page, however I want it to be about 1500px down from the top and as you scroll past it, it sticks to the bottom of the browser window. Can anybody give me some guidance on this one please?

Website is currently held here:
[Website Link](http://www.theres-a-thought.com/client-timmins)

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

1) Add `position: fixed;` to `#custom_footer`;

2) Add a big `margin-bottom` to `#csp3_content`.

This works for me:

```
#custom_footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

#csp3_content {
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I had forgotten I'd left a holding page up. You should see the actual site now....sorry

Comment: Well, the logic is the same. Basically you need to use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: relative`

Comment: Thanks Simone. That works for moving the footer to one static position on the page. But I want it so that when I scroll past it, it then sticks to the bottom of the browser window.

Comment: Oh well you need JavaScript for that. Try [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/), works pretty good

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding style `top:1500px;` and `position: fixed` to `#footer`

```
#footer {
 margin: 150px 0 0 0;
width: 960px;
float: left;
top: 1500px;
position: fixed;
color: white;
}
```